# Wireframing kit

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design

As a UX designer, I need to create wireframes quite often. As they're fast to create, I've stuck to basic shapes and text for quite a while, using custom text styles and symbols to make work faster.

However, I'm getting the feeling there's something to wireframe kits and I'd like to move to using one.

**Requirements:**

- Must be compatible with **Sketch** (not necessarily a Sketch file, could also be an SVG or PDF file)
- Must include web components
- Must not look like a finished product (so a wireframe kit, not a mock-up kit)
- Must include common web sections (e.g. a basic contact form)

**Niceties:**

- Android/iOS elements
- Simple licensing

Comment: What platform or OS do you require?

Comment: Sketch is Mac-only, so macOS compatibility at least.
Or did you mean wireframes for which platform? Web definitely, Android/iOS as a nice-to-have

Comment: Edit your Question to provide these additional requirements.

Comment: All of these are there, macOS is implied through Sketch compatibility